# asp:RequiredFieldValidator with the contents being a table row

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I've got the following code, which to my eye looks fine, can anyone suggest why it doesn't work?

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaserEmailTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="type-text" />
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="PurchaserEmailTextBox" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="Dynamic" runat="server">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <span class="error">You need a purchaser email</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The problem is that the validator renders fine, but refuses to disappear when the email is correctly filled in as it should.

Thanks!

Comment: Just tested successfully on my machine (error message disappeared after I filled in the email textbox).. Probably there is something else in the code/markup that causes the issue.

Comment: @Denis Ivin which browser you are using? Please show the code which is working.

Comment: @Denis no, the above code is not working in IE8 too

Comment: Just posted the code below.. I guess it's not a solution rather demonstrates my findings.

Comment: @sam: make sure compatibility mode is off.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing the following code snippet and it does work in IE8 for me (I didn't change anything):

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaserEmailTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="type-text" />
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="PurchaserEmailTextBox" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5"
            Display="Dynamic" runat="server">
                <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                     <span class="error">You need a purchaser email</span>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </table>
    <asp:Button Text="OK" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

However IE6, FF, Chrome are all failing but I think you could resolve that by replacing the fancy 'table' markup with divs, like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaserEmailTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="type-text" />
    </div>    
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="PurchaserEmailTextBox" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5"
        Display="Dynamic" runat="server">
            <div>
                <span class="error">You need a purchaser email</span>
            </div>
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button Text="OK" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the markup rendered by the validator:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="PurchaserEmailTextBox" type="text" value="asdf" id="PurchaserEmailTextBox" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <span id="RequiredFieldValidator5" style="color:Red;display:none;">
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2">
                 <span>You need a purchaser email</span>
               </td>
             </tr>
    </span>
</table>
```

The problem is there's a span element within the table element, which isn't allowed.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE

Answer (score 0):

I would say simply use the div element instead of your table way of display.

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaserEmailTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="type-text" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="PurchaserEmailTextBox" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You need a purchaser email"  />
</div>
```

It works fine for me in my applications